# How do I set a default chart type and a default scale type in Chart.js?

Tags: chart.js

I have a bunch of charts on a page, which are all 'line' charts, and they all use 'linear' scales on both X and Y axes. I would love to do away with having to do

```
    const graph1 = new Chart(ctx1, {
        type: 'line',
        options: {
            scales: {
                x: {
                    type: 'linear',
                },
                y: {
                    type: 'linear',
                },
            },
        },
    });
```

And instead just do:

```
    const graph1 = new Chart(ctx1, {});
```

I've tried setting `Chart.defaults.type` and `Chart.defaults.scales.type` to no avail.

Also `Chart.options.type`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid repetitive configuration, you may want to declare and initialize constants or variables with your default type and options, then use **ES6 shorthand syntax for object literals**.

Here is a possible implementation:

```js
const ctx1 = document.getElementById('myChart1'),
      ctx2 = document.getElementById('myChart2'),
      type = 'line',
      options = {
        scales: {
          x: {
            type: 'linear',
          },
          y: {
            type: 'linear',
          }
        }
      };

function addData(chart, data) {
  chart.data = { datasets: [] };
  chart.data.datasets.push(data);
  chart.update();
}

let chart1 = new Chart(ctx1, { type, options }); // <--- HERE

addData(chart1, {
  label: 'Dataset 1',
  data: [{ x: 0, y: 10 }, { x: 1, y: 20 }, { x: 2, y: 15 }]
});
  
let chart2 = new Chart(ctx2, { type, options }); // <--- HERE

addData(chart2, {
  label: 'Dataset 2',
  data: [{ x: 0, y: 7 }, { x: 1, y: 1 }, { x: 2, y: 3 }]
});
```

```css
.chart-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 40vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

<div class="chart-container">
  <canvas id="myChart1"></canvas>
</div>

<div class="chart-container">
  <canvas id="myChart2"></canvas>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT**

Below I put the same example with the **spread syntax** (`...`) as mentioned in my comment. This may be useful if you have some charts with specific options.

```js
const ctx1 = document.getElementById('myChart1'),
      ctx2 = document.getElementById('myChart2'),
      type = 'line',
      options = {
        scales: {
          x: {
            type: 'linear',
          },
          y: {
            type: 'linear',
          }
        }
      };

function addData(chart, data) {
  chart.data = { datasets: [] };
  chart.data.datasets.push(data);
  chart.update();
}
    
let chart1 = new Chart(ctx1, { type, options: {
  ...options, // <--- HERE
  animations: {
    tension: {
      duration: 1000,
      easing: 'linear',
      from: 1,
      to: 0,
      loop: true
    }
  }
}});

addData(chart1, {
  label: 'Dataset 1',
  data: [{ x: 0, y: 10 }, { x: 1, y: 20 }, { x: 2, y: 15 }]
});
  
let chart2 = new Chart(ctx2, { type, options: {
  ...options, // <--- HERE
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      labels: {
        color: 'red'
      }
    }
  }
}});

addData(chart2, {
  label: 'Dataset 2',
  data: [{ x: 0, y: 7 }, { x: 1, y: 1 }, { x: 2, y: 3 }]
});
```

```css
.chart-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 40vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

<div class="chart-container">
  <canvas id="myChart1"></canvas>
</div>

<div class="chart-container">
  <canvas id="myChart2"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: That works, but what if I have some specific options for some charts, is there a way to avoid having to list the scales there?

Comment: To expand on that, I thought of having a base options object, and copying it and then adding the fields I want. But that gets a little... involved, especially since there isn't a native deep copy/clone AFAIK.

Comment: If you have specific options for some charts, you may want to use the spread (`...`) syntax on the default object to add new options more easily. But it depends on what kind of configuration you want to modify. I am not sure there is a perfect solution in your case. Like **ECharts** and **ApexCharts**, **Chart.js** relies on a main object literal to configure charts. This is how it has been designed. Other libraries, like **amCharts 5**, offer something different in terms of code organization...

Comment: What would that look like?

Comment: I edited my answer and updated my example. The spread syntax is really useful, but it might be overkill if you also need to change the options for scales...